# Recursive wait for keyPress in Python

Tags: python, keyboard-events, can-bus

I have a CAN data log file, that I am splitting into two equal parts based on line numbers. I play this file using `canplayer`, observe a behaviour on simulator and then press `y/n`, where y - behavior observed, or n- behavior not observed.

```
code logic:
 1. split file into two parts based on line numbers or entries.
 2. play file1, observe behavior
 3. if behavior observed, take file1, split into two parts again and follow same procedure
```

**(in case of behaviour is not observed in file1, do the following or ignore)**

```
 2*. play file2, observe behavior 
 3*. if behavior observed, take file2, split into two parts again and follow same procedure
```

I have the following code:

```
def runParser(self):
    #get the number of lines in file
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(self.fileName))
    print(num_lines)
    if(num_lines % 2 == 0):
        splitLen = num_lines/2
    else:
        splitLen = num_lines/2 + 1

    self.splitFile(splitLen) # successfully splits the file and outputs two new files.
    command = "canplayer -I {}".format(self.out1.name)
    #print(command)
    os.system(command)
    print('Do you see the behaviour? press y/n')
    keyboard.on_press(self.accessBehavior)

def accessBehavior(self,event):
    if event.name == 'y':
        self.fileName = self.out1.name
        self.runParser()

    if event.name == 'n':
        command = "canplayer -I {}".format(self.out2.name)
        print(command)
        os.system(command)
        self.fileName= self.out2.name
        self.runParser()

def splitFile(self, len):
    self.fin = open(self.fileName,'rb')
    self.out1 = open('out{}.log'.format(self.fileCount),'wb')
    self.fileCount+=1 # initialized to zero
    self.out2 = open('out{}.log'.format(self.fileCount),'wb')
    self.fileCount+=1

    count=0
    for line in self.fin:
        count +=1
        if count >= len:
            #write to new file
            self.out2.write(line)
        else:
            self.out1.write(line)

    self.fin.close()
    self.out1.close()
    self.out2.close()
```

1. The problem I face, is that the `keyboard.on_press(self.accessBehavior)`, waits only for the first press. I want the program to accept multiple `y/n` press based on the behaviour I see after running the command `canplayer ..`
2. So, if the behaviour is not observed, I press `n`, and the steps keep repeating till all the data in file is exhausted and only one row of data is present in file, which invokes the behaviour.

Here is a sample of how CAN data file looks:

```
(1584526791.145716) vcan0 13F#000000050000001F
(1584526791.145719) vcan0 164#0000C01AA8000031
(1584526791.145721) vcan0 17C#0000000010000012
(1584526791.145723) vcan0 18E#00005C
(1584526791.147489) vcan0 183#0000000D0000101D
(1584526791.147526) vcan0 143#6B6B00D1
(1584526791.149458) vcan0 095#800007F400000008
(1584526791.153293) vcan0 166#D0320018
(1584526791.153332) vcan0 158#0000000000000019
(1584526791.153335) vcan0 161#000005500108001C
(1584526791.153337) vcan0 191#010090A1410003
(1584526791.153360) vcan0 244#0000000142
(1584526791.154416) vcan0 133#00000000A7
(1584526791.154447) vcan0 136#000200000000002A
(1584526791.154450) vcan0 13A#0000000000000028
(1584526791.154452) vcan0 13F#000000050000002E
(1584526791.154454) vcan0 164#0000C01AA8000004
(1584526791.156373) vcan0 17C#0000000010000021
 .....
 .....
 .....
```

Comment: Small note, but in Python something like 15/2+1 is still going to be a float. You'd want to math.ceil(num_lines/2) or use integer division like num_lines//2.

Comment: Can you store all the lines in memory? If so it might be easier split your lines into arrays instead of back into files and wrap runParser in a while loop that terminates when the array only has 1 row left or the behavior is observed.

Comment: @Michael Storing them as arrays, would involve an additional step, where I need to decode a row like `(1584526791.154454) vcan0 164#0000C01AA8000004` `(CAN_ID#Data)`, -> into  `164#0000C01AA8000004` to obtain the CAN ID and data  so that I can replay this and observe the behavior on the simulator.